# How to "save" current View on Navigation stack and all previous Views when close and reopen the App?

Tags: ios, swift

My App has 6 Views (View 1->6) in a Navigation stack.

Requirement is, if user is at View 4 then close the app and reopen, the app must show View 4 and user can back to View 3->2->1.

The problem is i can save current view (save View index by UserDefault) index but cannot save previous Views. If i reopen the app, previous Views need to be renew, how to do it ?

Please help me, and sorry for my English.

Comment: see this for e.g : https://useyourloaf.com/blog/state-preservation-and-restoration/

Comment: previous Views need to be renew, how to do it ?

Là sao hở Dang Nguyen?

Answer (score 0):

basically, the easiest way will be to save current path at user defaults, something like
`app/navigation/vc1/vc2/vc3`

On start of your app you'll need to read this path, separate it by components, and restore your navigation controller with instantiated view controllers.

Answer (score -1):

Try insert view 1... to current index after viewdidload. Sample code:

```
  -(void)insertView:(int)currentIndex{
    NSMutableArray *newControllers = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:self.navigationController.viewControllers];
    for(int i = 0; i < currentIndex; i++){
        UIViewController *vc  = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
        vc.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        [newControllers insertObject:vc atIndex:0];
    }
    [self.navigationController setViewControllers:newControllers];
}
```

Comment: It 's just solution.

Comment: @Moritz
I do not intend to work for his tasks, I just share what I have, this is the solution to solve his problems, he should brainstorming about what I mentioned.
And instead of making irrelevant remarks, you should contribute more reasonable answers.